# omit / remove '<br>' from category list

Tags: plugins

used this code and that did not worked for me.

```
echo str_replace( "<br>", "", wp_list_categories(array('title_li' => false, 'style' => false)));
```

what did I missed?

Comment: Please use the tools to format your text and code, and explain your problem not only in title. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace '<br>' with '' by setting **separator** value

```
echo wp_list_categories(array('title_li' => false, 'style' => false, 'separator' => ''));
```

Comment: if I keep it blank then there won't be any <br> right?

Comment: yes it will remove <br> tag

Answer (score 1):

```
Please use below code it will help you
 $args = [
    'style'     => 'none',
    'separator' => '', // <-- Removes the default one
];

wp_list_categories( $args );
```